# Fixed tab-spacing for TextEdit on Mac

Tags: mac, big-sur, text-editor, textedit, tabs

Is there a way to set a fixed number of spaces for a tab indent? If not, can someone recommend a program that is simple like TextEdit, but also *does* have fixed tab spacing?

Comment: Textedit is a baby word processor with **very limited** options. I don't believe this is possible, but there are a large number of text editors with an option to set all of those things. BBEdit is a good one and is one of the longest running apps harking back to the Classic MacOS days.

Answer (score -1):

If meaning of 'tab indent' is 'tab stop' in [TextEdit User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/textedit/welcome/mac) jargon then you can follow instructions in [Set tab stops](https://support.apple.com/guide/textedit/adjust-margins-and-paragraphs-txte313927e3/1.16/mac/11.0#txteec320cfa) (short: while ruler visible manually drag tabs stop width)